# Entity Framework & Oracle, Linq where clause string comparisons do not return any records if given a function parameter rather than a literal

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I am writing a C# app in .Net Core v.2.2.300 which uses the Entity Framework and Devart.Data.Oracle to extract source code from our Oracle Database using the SYS.DBA_SOURCE table in the database which stores each line of database code as a single record. The purpose being for us to do some automated analysis. To do this, I have created a function GetSourceCode which is passed a schema name, an object name, and the object type (PACKAGE / FUNCTION etc.). This function uses Linq and filters dba_source(OWNER, NAME, TYPE, LINE, TEXT) to only records in which the given owner, name, and type match those given in the function's parameters. However, this query always returns nothing when using the parameters even though I have verified directly with the database that the records exist and should have been retrieved. If I hard-code string values into the query then it does work, but that negates the purpose of using a function. The database user I am using can connect to the database and does have permission to view the table in question so it is not a permission issue but I believe has something to do with the Linq to SQL conversion.

Hard coding string values into the where clause comparison works to fetch data but not with the values passed as parameters unless we copy the parameters (using the string copy constructor) within the clause (copying does nothing outside of the where clause).

After experimenting with the query I have found a way to get the function to work by using the copy constructors, but doing this results in a slow query taking minutes to get the source code of a single script which is not feasible for us to make use of.

I believe it is this copying of the string on each check of the where clause that is causing the program to be so slow.

Mainly I would like to know why I am seeing the behavior I am seeing as well as how I could alter the linq query to use the function's arguments without creating this huge slowdown.

The following source code does not work and always returns an empty string even though I can use the equivalent sql directly in my database with the same parameters and get the correct results (the source code of the indicated file)

```cs
private string GetSourceCode(string name, string owner, string oracleType) {
var qry = DbaSource
                .Where((row) => (
                    row.Name.Equals(name) &&
                    row.Type.Equals(oracleType) &&
                    row.Owner.Equals(owner)
                )).OrderBy((row) => row.Line)
                .Select((row) => row.Text)
                .ToList()
                .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, line) => sb.AppendLine(line), sb => sb.ToString());

return qry;
}
```

However, I can hard code values and get the correct results for those inputs

```cs
var qry = DbaSource
                .Where((row) => (
                    row.Name.Equals("Example Table Name") &&
                    row.Type.Equals("PACKAGE") &&
                    row.Owner.Equals("Example Schema Name")
                )).OrderBy((row) => row.Line)
                .Select((row) => row.Text)
                .ToList()
                .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, line) => sb.AppendLine(line), sb => sb.ToString());
```

or I can perform this copying which I believe has lead to my program's huge loss in performance.

```cs
var qry = DbaSource
                .Where((row) => (
                    row.Name.Equals(new string(name)) &&
                    row.Type.Equals(new string(oracleType)) &&
                    row.Owner.Equals(new string(owner))
                )).OrderBy((row) => row.Line)
                .Select((row) => row.Text)
                .ToList()
                .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, line) => sb.AppendLine(line), sb => sb.ToString());
```

Where the DbaSource object is described by

```
public DbSet<Models.Sys.DbaSource> DbaSource {get; set;}

namespace Models.Sys {

[Table("DBA_SOURCE", Schema="SYS")]
    public class DbaSource{
        [Column("OWNER", Order = 0)]
        public string Owner {get; set;}

        [Column("NAME", Order = 1)]
        public string Name {get; set;}

        [Column("TYPE", Order = 2)]
        public string Type {get; set;}

        [Column("LINE", Order = 3)]
        public decimal Line {get; set;}

        [Column("TEXT")]
        public string Text {get; set;}

        [Column("ORIGIN_CON_ID")]
        public decimal OriginConId {get; set;}

        public static Expression<Func<DbaSource, object>> GetPrimaryKey() {
            return r => new { r.Owner, r.Name, r.Type, r.Line };
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}|{4}|{5}", Owner, Name, Type, Line, Text, OriginConId);
        }
    }

}
```

I hope that is enough information to describe the issue that I am seeing as this behavior is entirely unexpected, difficult to describe, and not at all logical to me but given my limited experience with the Entity Framework I believe there is something going on with the Linq to SQL that is the issue.

I expect to get the source code for a given database object as a single string within seconds using a function which allows me to pass in different values for different objects within a reasonable time frame.

I actually get a situation where either I get nothing no matter what the input is as the comparisons in the where clause just do not work even if the inputs should produce the correct values or I get a situation where it works but is 100x slower than it should be due to adding weird string copies which somehow get it to do the right thing.

Comment: What if you just do `row.Name == name` instead.  Since it translates to SQL it's hard to say what the Oracle provider might be doing with `Equals`.  Also you can see what the generated SQL is by assigning the query (everything before the `ToList` to a variable and calling `ToString` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the EF QueryProvider wont convert `row.Name.Equals(name)` correctly. You should use `row.Name == name` instead.

Comment: So I switched the .Equals to == as per your suggestion but I have the same behavior, I get 0 results unless I copy each of the parameters using new string within the where clause. With simple string comparisons, row.Name == name, I get 0 results but using row.Name == new string(name) I get 1300 results.